# Using executemany in SQLite3 for an UPDATE statement

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I am attempting to use execute many to update two columns in a sqlite3 database. I am using a pandas dataframe to store information about some tiff image files- their height, width (both integers) and using their file name (string) as the WHERE clause.

```
import ImageQA
import os
import sqlite3
home_directory = os.getcwd()
image_file_set = ImageQA.get_image_size(shelfmark_reference,working_directory)
#image_count = len(image_file_set))
tiff_file_list = list(image_file_set['TiffFile'])
height_list = list(image_file_set['Height'])
width_list = list(image_file_set['Width'])
zipped = zip(height_list,width_list,tiff_file_list)
file_list = list(zipped)
os.chdir(home_directory)
conn = sqlite3.connect('DigiFolio')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.executemany('UPDATE Capture_information SET Height = ?,Width = ? WHERE TiffFileName =?',file_list)
conn.close()
```

The code runs fine, but when I query the database to see if the information has been entered correctly the Height and Width columns remain empty.

I think I know the problem, but have not managed to resolve it. Using ? to pass the third parameter means that there are not any quotation marks around the string in the WHERE statement. However, if I put quotes around the question mark, I get the following error- "Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 2, and there are 3 supplied." Suggesting that the quotation marks render the ? not unrecognizable as a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not necessary to quote the string fields, in fact it can cause problems as you have discovered. However...

From the [python sqlite API doc](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.commit):

> **commit()**
>
> This method commits the current transaction. If you don’t call this method, anything you did since the last call to commit() is not
>   visible from other database connections. If you wonder why you don’t
>   see the data you’ve written to the database, please check you didn’t
>   forget to call this method.

Comment: Thank you so much. Relieved, if feeling a bit dopey, that it's such a simple fix.